# Picasa Video Direct Link

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I'm trying to get the direct link to picasa Video, because I want to share that to the public, but I'm unable to find out the link.

This is the link to video the video:
http://azdrama.net/watch-online-horse-doctor-episode-01-22904.html

This is the google video playback id

> googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=eff0b23afc08189a

My question: is there a way to view/play the video by going directly to the video back on video playback id and not having to going to the website?

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to change the privacy/sharing settings of the particular video/ album in which the video is stored to "Anyone who has a link" and only then you can share it by sending the link via message to your friends.